# (415) Unsupported Media Type : Same script works on my laptop but not on azure runbook ((415) Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: html, azure, powershell, sendgrid

I m using a powershell script to send email with some links on the body.
The script runs well on my laptop
Here a screenshot of what the mail received looks like

[received message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHWst.png)

However it got an error when run from Azure powershell automation runbook
Here the error message:

```
    Send-SendGridEmail : Error with Invoke-RestMethod The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.

At line:176 char:1

+ Send-SendGridEmail @splat

+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Send-SendGridEmail



### Inside catch ###

## ErrorMessage ##

The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.

## FailedItem ##


## result2 ##



CanTimeout   : True

ReadTimeout  : -1

WriteTimeout : -1

CanRead      : True

CanSeek      : True

CanWrite     : True

Capacity     : 256

Length       : 156

Position     : 156

## reader ##



CurrentEncoding          BaseStream                  EndOfStream

---------------          ----------                  -----------

System.Text.UTF8Encoding System.Net.SyncMemoryStream        True

## responseBody ##
```

Here is my code:

```
function Send-SendGridEmail {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String] $destEmailAddress,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String] $fromEmailAddress,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String] $subject,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$contentType = 'text/html',
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String] $contentBody
  )

  <#
.Synopsis
Function to send email with SendGrid
.Description
A function to send a text or HTML based email
See https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/api_v3.html for API details
This script provided as-is with no warranty. Test it before you trust it.
www.ciraltos.com
.Parameter apiKey
The SendGrid API key associated with your account
.Parameter destEmailAddress
The destination email address
.Parameter fromEmailAddress
The from email address
.Parameter subject
Email subject
.Parameter type
The content type, values are “text/plain” or “text/html”.  "text/plain" set by default
.Parameter content
The content that you'd like to send
.Example
Send-SendGridEmail
#>

  ############ Update with your SendGrid API Key ####################
  $apiKey = "APIKeyGoesHere"

  $headers = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $apiKey
    'Content-Type'  = 'application/json'
    'Content-transfer-encoding' = 'quoted-printable'
    #'Content-transfer-encoding' = '7bit'
  }

  $body = @{
    personalizations = @(
      @{
        to = @(
          @{
            email = $destEmailAddress
          }
        )
      }
    )

    from             = @{
      email = $fromEmailAddress
    }
    subject          = $subject
    content          = @(
      @{
        type  = $contentType
        value = $contentBody
      }
    )
  }

  try {
    $bodyJson = $body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4
    Write-Host $bodyJson
  }
  catch {
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.message
    write-error ('Error converting body to json ' + $ErrorMessage)
    Break
  }

  try {
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $bodyJson 
  }
  catch {
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.message
    write-error ('Error with Invoke-RestMethod ' + $ErrorMessage)
     echo '### Inside catch ###'
   $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
   echo '## ErrorMessage ##' $ErrorMessage
  $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
  echo '## FailedItem ##' $FailedItem 
  $result = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
     echo '## result2 ##' $result
    $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($result)
     echo '## reader ##' $reader 
    $responseBody = $reader.ReadToEnd();
     echo '## responseBody ##' $responseBody
    Break
  }

}



$Link1 = "http://www.google.com"
$Link2 = "http://www.google.com"
$Link3 = "http://www.google.com"

$LienBlob = "https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Storage/ContainerMenuBlade/overview/storageAccountId/%2Fsubscriptions%2Fe84d34eb-168f-4678-ac5b-1cee0d6b9666%2FresourceGroups%2Frg-prd-weu-itadmin%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Storage%2FstorageAccounts%2Fsastditadminwesteuprd/path/rbac-reports/etag/%220x8D7EC1F1F6E014B%22"

$htmlBody = @"
<table>
<tr>
<td align="left">
<p>Hello,</p>
<p>Test message</p>
<p><a href=$Link1>Link 1</a></p>
<p><a href=$Link2>Link 1</a></p>
<p><a href=$Link3>Link 1</a></p>
<p>Thank you,<br /><font size="-1"><i>Automatic message. Please do not reply.</i></font></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
"@


$mySubject = "TesMail"

$splat = @{
  destEmailAddress = 'maatoug.wassim@gmail.com'
  fromEmailAddress = 'donotreply@my.net'
  subject          = $mySubject
  contentType      = 'text/html'
  contentBody      = $htmlBody
  }
Send-SendGridEmail @splat
```

It happens that, on the azure powershell runbook, when reducing the html body to only one line, example

```
<table>
<tr>
<td align="left">
<p>Hello,</p>
<p>Test message</p> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
"@
```

It do work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Send-SendGridEmail : Error with Invoke-RestMethod The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.

This causes all the headers after the Authorization header to be treated as the message body and effectively ignored. A simple pass through `trim` will fix this:

`$apiKey = trim($apiKey);`

For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/issues/580#issuecomment-366902261).